# Override copy past functionality of a WPF grid view

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, overriding, copy-paste

I have a WPF DataGrid with one column:

```
 <DataGrid Name="myGRID">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="myHeader Binding="{Binding myObservableCollection}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="tbx_ConcernEnter_TextChanged"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now i want to override the paste function of the rows.
When i use:

```
<DataGrid>
<CommandBinding Command="Paste" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
</DataGrid>
```

this seems to be the override for the whole GridView but not for a specific row.

Do you know how to override this?

Comment: Specific row? Do you mean a specific column?

Comment: No, i want to click into a specific row of my gridview and say "past" for example. This shall call a function in my codebehind

Comment: This should happen when you click into *any* row then, right? What's the difference between this and "this seems to be the override for the whole GridView but not for a specific row"?

Comment: To test the behavour, i added a function that simply shows a messagebox when die commandbinding is executed. When i click into a cell and say "paste" the command is not executed. But when i do not select any cell, click on the header of my column and then say ctrl+v, the textbox is shown, which means the command has been executed. this is not what i want. I want to override the paste command for the specific input cell

Comment: Do you want the command to be executed when the cell is in edit mode only?

Comment: yes, this is exactelly what i want

Comment: What's wrong with handling the TextChanged event then?

Comment: I want to override the paste function and put all the functionality into a function in the code behind. therefore i need a handler which recognizes if the user uses ctrl+v or clicks on paste via the context menu

Comment: Right, please refer to my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate` "swallows" the paste command. But you could handle the `Loaded` event for the `TextBox` and hook up a `Pasting` event handler to it:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <EventSetter Event="TextChanged" Handler="tbx_ConcernEnter_TextChanged"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="TextBox_Loaded" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

---

```
private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBox, OnPaste);
}

private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    //paste detected...
}
```

Comment: It Works. Thanks a lot mm8 for your patience!